# How do I map my data from a list into tuple?

Tags: python

I want to get this

```
[('106', '1', '1', '43009'), ('106', '1', '2', '43179'), ('106', '1', '3', '43189'), ('106', '1', '4', '43619'), ('106', '1', '5', '43629')]
```

This is my code

```
def read_route_data(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        lines = list(f)
        return map(lambda x: x[:-1], lines) # [:-1] is to remove the last character


bus_stations = read_route_data('smrt_routes.txt')
print(bus_stations[:5])
```

which I got `['106,1,1,43009', '106,1,2,43179', '106,1,3,43189', '106,1,4,43619', '106,1,5,43629']` instead of it in the tuple. How do I do it such that my str is in the tuple? I tried  return map(lambda x: (x[:-1],), lines) which give me an extra comma at the back.

Comment: Your forgot to apply `str.split` on the strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
>>> foo = ['106,1,1,43009', '106,1,2,43179', '106,1,3,43189', '106,1,4,43619', '106,1,5,43629']
>>> [tuple(f.split(",")) for f in foo]
[('106', '1', '1', '43009'), ('106', '1', '2', '43179'), ('106', '1', '3', '43189'), ('106', '1', '4', '43619'), ('106', '1', '5', '43629')]
```

We're using a list comprehension to filter each of the keys, `.split()` to split each string into a list, and `tuple()` to convert that list into a tuple

Comment: Okay I got it. Tahnk you so much Ian !!

Comment: No problem, if this answer solved your problem, please mark it as such.